# Algorithms for realtime strategy wargame AI

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I'm designing a realtime strategy wargame where the AI will be responsible for controlling a large number of units (possibly 1000+) on a large hexagonal map.

A unit has a number of action points which can be expended on movement, attacking enemy units or various special actions (e.g. building new units). For example, a tank with 5 action points could spend 3 on movement then 2 in firing on an enemy within range. Different units have different costs for different actions etc.

Some additional notes:

- The output of the AI is a "command" to any given unit
- Action points are allocated at the beginning of a time period, but may be spent at any point within the time period (this is to allow for realtime multiplayer games). Hence "do nothing and save action points for later" is a potentially valid tactic (e.g. a gun turret that cannot move waiting for an enemy to come within firing range)
- The game is updating in realtime, but the AI can get a consistent snapshot of the game state at any time (thanks to the game state being one of Clojure's persistent data structures)
- I'm not expecting "optimal" behaviour, just something that is not obviously stupid and provides reasonable fun/challenge to play against

What can you recommend in terms of specific algorithms/approaches that would allow for the right balance between efficiency and reasonably intelligent behaviour?

Comment: Is this real-time?  Using action points for moving and shooting sounds more turn-based?  In a real-time game I'd expect to hear about rate of movement and rate of fire.  How do action points "recharge"?

Comment: The design of APs is more turn-based, but I'm trying to ensure the game can run in realtime so it can work in a multiplayer context. The current concept I'm playing with is that the action points get refreshed at a regular interval

Comment: OK, I've now got a demo version running on Amazon if anyone is interested: http://184.73.157.186/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you should aim to make your game turn based at some level for the AI (i.e. you can somehow model it turn based even if it may not be entirely turn based, in RTS you may be able to break discrete intervals of time into turns.) Second, you should determine how much information the AI should work with. That is, if the AI is allowed to cheat and know every move of its opponent (thereby making it stronger) or if it should know less or more. Third, you should define a cost function of a state. The idea being that a higher cost means a worse state for the computer to be in. Fourth you need a move generator, generating all valid states the AI can transition to from a given state (this may be homogeneous [state-independent] or heterogeneous [state-dependent].)

The thing is, the cost function will be greatly influenced by what exactly you define the state to be. The more information you encode in the state the better balanced your AI will be but the more difficult it will be for it to perform, as it will have to search exponentially more for every additional state variable you include (in an exhaustive search.)

If you provide a definition of a state and a cost function your problem transforms to a general problem in AI that can be tackled with any algorithm of your choice.

Here is a summary of what I think would work well:

1. Evolutionary algorithms may work well if you put enough effort into them, but they will add a layer of complexity that will create room for bugs amongst other things that can go wrong. They will also require extreme amounts of tweaking of the fitness function etc. I don't have much experience working with these but if they are anything like neural networks (which I believe they are since both are heuristics inspired by biological models) you will quickly find they are fickle and far from consistent. Most importantly, I doubt they add any benefits over the option I describe in 3.
2. With the cost function and state defined it would technically be possible for you to apply gradient decent (with the assumption that the state function is differentiable and the domain of the state variables are continuous) however this would probably yield inferior results, since the biggest weakness of gradient descent is getting stuck in local minima. To give an example, this method would be prone to something like attacking the enemy always as soon as possible because there is a non-zero chance of annihilating them. Clearly, this may not be desirable behaviour for a game, however, gradient decent is a greedy method and doesn't know better.
3. This option would be my most highest recommended one: simulated annealing. Simulated annealing would (IMHO) have all the benefits of 1. without the added complexity while being much more robust than  2. In essence SA is just a random walk amongst the states. So in addition to the cost and states you will have to define a way to randomly transition between states. SA is also not prone to be stuck in local minima, while producing very good results quite consistently. The only tweaking required with SA would be the cooling schedule--which decides how fast SA will converge. The greatest advantage of SA I find is that it is conceptually simple and produces superior results empirically to most other methods I have tried. Information on SA can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) with a long list of generic implementations at the bottom.

3b. (*Edit Added much later*) SA and the techniques I listed above are general AI techniques and not really specialized to AI for games. In general, the more specialized the algorithm the more chance it has at performing better. See No Free Lunch Theorem [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_in_search_and_optimization). Another extension of 3 is something called parallel tempering which dramatically improves the performance of SA by helping it avoid local optima. Some of the original papers on parallel tempering are quite dated [3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9710041.pdf), but others have been updated[4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0407273.pdf).

Regardless of what method you choose in the end, its going to be very important to break your problem down into states and a cost function as I said earlier. As a rule of thumb I would start with 20-50 state variables as your state search space is exponential in the number of these variables.

Comment: Nitpick: surely you mean, stuck on local maxima?

Comment: you know... best thing would be if someone shown an example of what can be the "state" in these types of games...

Answer (score 11):

If you read [Russell and Norvig](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/), you'll find a wealth of algorithms for every purpose, updated to pretty much today's state of the art. That said, I was amazed at how many different problem classes can be successfully approached with Bayesian algorithms.

However, in your case I think it would be a bad idea for each unit to have its own Petri net or inference engine... there's only so much CPU and memory and time available. Hence, a different approach:

While in some ways perhaps a crackpot, [Stephen Wolfram](http://www.wolframscience.com/) has shown that it's possible to program remarkably complex behavior on a basis of [very simple rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_automaton). He bravely extrapolates from the [Game of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway's_Game_of_Life) to quantum physics and the entire universe.

Similarly, a lot of research on small robots is focusing on [emergent behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emergence) or [swarm intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swarm_intelligence). While classic [military strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_strategy) and practice are strongly based on hierarchies, I think that an army of completely selfless, fearless fighters (as can be found marching in your computer) could be remarkably effective if operating as self-organizing clusters.

This approach would probably fit a little better with Erlang's or Scala's actor-based concurrency model than with Clojure's STM: I think self-organization and actors would go together extremely well. Still, I could envision running through a list of units at each turn, and having each unit evaluating just a small handful of very simple rules to determine its next action. I'd be very interested to hear if you've tried this approach, and how it went!

**EDIT**

Something else that was on the back of my mind but that slipped out again while I was writing: I think you can get remarkable results from this approach if you combine it with [genetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm) or evolutionary programming; i.e. let your virtual toy soldiers wage war on each other as you sleep, let them encode their strategies and mix, match and mutate their code for those strategies; and let a refereeing program select the more successful warriors.

I've read about some startling successes achieved with these techniques, with units operating in ways we'd never think of. I have heard of AIs working on these principles having had to be intentionally dumbed down in order not to frustrate human opponents.

Comment: AIMA is a great introduction to AI, but it's far from the state of the art.

Answer (score 9):

This question is huge in scope. You are basically asking how to write a strategy game.

There are tons of books and online articles for this stuff. I strongly recommend the *Game Programming Wisdom* series and *AI Game Programming Wisdom* series. In particular, Section 6 of the first volume of *AI Game Programming Wisdom* covers general architecture, Section 7 covers decision-making architectures, and Section 8 covers architectures for specific genres (8.2 does the RTS genre).

Comment: To clarify - I'm more interested in specific algorithmic ideas that would work for this context rather than the overall model. Have edited question to reflect.

Answer (score 7):

It's a huge question, and the other answers have pointed out amazing resources to look into.

I've dealt with this problem in the past and found the simple-behavior-manifests-complexly/emergent behavior approach a bit too unwieldy for human design unless approached genetically/evolutionarily.

I ended up instead using abstracted layers of AI, similar to a way armies work in real life.  Units would be grouped with nearby units of the same time into squads, which are grouped with nearby squads to create a mini battalion of sorts.  More layers could be use here (group battalions in a region, etc.), but ultimately at the top there is the high-level strategic AI.

Each layer can only issue commands to the layers directly below it.  The layer below it will then attempt to execute the command with the resources at hand (ie, the layers below that layer).

An example of a command issued to a single unit is "Go here" and "shoot at this target".  Higher level commands issued to higher levels would be "secure this location", which that level would process and issue the appropriate commands to the lower levels.

The highest level master AI is responsible for very board strategic decisions, such as "we need more ____ units", or "we should aim to move towards this location".

The army analogy works here; commanders and lieutenants and chain of command.

Answer (score 0):

Google did have an AI for RTS that could beat a pro Starcraft 2 player in specialized case. The AI was a pure deep neural network. That being said never use machine learning for your AI because despite their strength ML suck for games (balance, quirks, long learning time period, bad at mods). ML is a last resort for games and RTS.
Use a generalized chess engine, that is a Monte Carlo Tree Search (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_tree_search). Should work with almost anything without using ML tough these engines are weak for RTS games if you have limited visibility of the battle field.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).