# Making a tile map

Tags: c#

I am creating a tower defense game, i need help with a method or program to make it a tile map so then i can slowly input enemies on a road have turrets that shoot at them etc, i have already tried:

- Inputting a picture one by one which i failed on.
- Also i tried using the program called tiled but i failed on understand how that makes it tile map so i am pretty lost on the definition on tile map now.

Could someone make some suggestions, links, explanations would be very helpful?

Comment: As it stands now this question is very broad. Please narrow down your question to something more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can load maps generated by 'Tiled' using '[TiledSharp](https://github.com/marshallward/TiledSharp)'.

You'll have to figure another way for getting the enemies to move on the map, getting the towers to shoot them, etc. Try this for a start:
[Algorithms for realtime strategy wargame AI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275174/algorithms-for-realtime-strategy-wargame-ai)

You can also try to use [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com) that might already have something ready for use (unless, of course, the reason is for you to learn the algorithms rather than making the game).

If you need more help please specify exactly what it is you're looking for, i.e. displaying the map, moving the forces, shooting at the forces, UI, etc.